# ASP.NET MVC 3 authentication on the root directory, without redirect (Ajax)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, authentication, path

I'm writing an ajax application, I'm using the atribute allowanonymous for autentication ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx )

today, as soon as anybody access the web application, it will redirect to ~/Account/LogOn and when the login is successful it will return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); and the browser URL will show: http:// website/ and from there I only use ajax calls, so the URL stays the same. (the content is called using json and the returned data is included in a main div)

**I'm willing to make the URL be the root directory (http://website/) on the logon page as well.** How can I accomplish it? I want the whole webapp to be in ajax, with no redirects. If I apply Ajax the way it is right now, the URL will stay as http:// website/Account/LogOn even after the login is already made.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest installing MVC 4, it has a default template that does exactly what you want, called a single page app.  You don't have to use MVC4 for your app, but you can base your app on the same techniques.  That way you can update to MVC4 when it is released with little issue.

MVC4 is currently in Beta, but is expected to be released this summer.  MVC4 is also avaialable with a Go-Live license, so you can publish production sites with it.

It would also help if you used the right terminology.  MVC has Action Methods and routes, not "directories".  Routes are arbitrary and do not match to physical directories on the server.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I still didn't took a look at MVC4, but I found a way to do what I was willing to do.
And thank you for correcting the term I used. I wasn't really sure how to explain what I wanted in the title.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do, I edited my default route to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/" timeout="120" />
</authentication>
```

LogOn Method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult LogOn()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return View("Home"); //Show welcome message
    }
    return View(); //Show logon form
}
```

This did the trick :)